# Lyon at night - where to eat?

Tags: france, food-and-drink, lyon

Are there any places that serve food late at night (after 23:00) around Vieux Lyon or between 1st and 2nd arrondissement? I'm thinking wine bars that serve charcuterie perhaps, or street food…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yelp says [yes](http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=rest&find_loc=Lyon&ns=1&ls=323e2b0e6d16dcce#open_time=4264&l=p:FR-69:Lyon::[1er_arrondissement,2%C3%A8me_arrondissement]), there appear to be two. Yelp has filters to search for specific areas and opening hours (see screen dumps below).

[image][image]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @andra! Both those places are less than a 5-minute walk from my hotel.

Comment: *Open at* is not equivalent to *serves food*. I know quite some restaurant that are open (for serving beverages) for a longer time than their kitchen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper They're less than 5 minutes from the OP's hotel. I'm sure the OP can check.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's not common in France (such places are rare and we wouldn't call them restaurants). Incidentally, many (most?) restaurants don't have the right to serve alcohol without meals.

Comment: @Relaxed: Oh, ok, wasn't aware of that. I've seen many (most?) restaurants in other European countries such as Germany that would offer at least warm dishes only till 10 PM, but stay open afterward for another hour or two because guests like to keep sitting around, socialize, and have one or two more glasses of coke or whatever else. (It's rather the "non-restaurants", fast food places and food counters, that offer food all the time there.)

Comment: Opening times for restaurants are usually "last table available" rather than the time they actually close the doors.  If you've ever worked in a restaurant that officially closes at 2300, you'd know you rarely leave before midnight.

Answer (score 5):

The Moonshine bar on 15 Rue des Quatre Chapeaux served this today a little past midnight (plus bread and very yummy little pickles):

[image]

Disclaimer: I am not associated with them. This is not spam (but rather, they were quality meats).